# Чем отличается квалификатор/спецификатор/модификатор?

Tags: java, c++, ооп

Так вышло, что изучаю одновременно С++ и Java. Запутался чем отличается квалификатор от спецификатора от модификатора в этих языках. На сколько я понял в Java нет термина "квалификатор". Это верно?

Comment: У каждого языка своя терминология, так что не парьтесь. Вон слово «ссылка» в C++ и Java означает кардинально разные вещи.

Comment: Запутался даже в рамках 1го языка

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще говоря, это зависит от конкретной сущности. Например, **"модификатор"** чаще употребляется со словом "доступ" - три общепринятых модификатора.

**Спецификатор** - чаще, в связке со "специфичностью" чего-либо - например, константность ячейки памяти - "const"(в этом примере спецификатором может выступать и тип константы - зависит от точки, с которой рассматривается "специфичность").

А **квалификатором**, например, может являться особое свойство - первое, что приходит на ум - ключевые слова "sealed"/"final", предоставляющие классу "квалификацию" на запрет имения потомков.

P.S Вообще говоря, вполне может показаться, что все это высосано из пальца(по сути, так и есть), но это лишь подчеркивает, что конкретный смысл зависит от контекста(языка), в котором оно употребляется и от языка. Так, например, модификатор/квалификатор/спецификатор *доступа* - в большинстве случаев одно и то же.

Comment: ответ разумный и в конечном итоге смысла в словах ровно столько сколько носители языка в них вкладывают, но НО: существуют формальные [определения](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) [языков](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), в которых слова имеют вполне определённый строго заданный смысл и тогда остаётся только  вопрос как на русский перевести (что не является механической деятельностью, но связь с оригиналом должна быть). Если намёк на (вполне разумные) определения, данные в ответе, соответствует как эти слова в фактических спецификациях языков используются, то стоит это упомянуть.

Answer (score 0):

термин есть. `google://"qualifier site:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8"`

смотрите в спецификацию языка всегда, найдете там и термины и синонимы для них

P.S. в целом это все - по смыслу - синонимы, но, как правило, существует точные, правильные названия из спецификации. Их и следует использовать.